# Namespace issue with NSLocation authorization iOS8?

Tags: ios8, cllocationmanager

I have a Swift iOS8 app that uses CoreLocation and APNS and everything worked fine.  After everything got smoothed out, I created a new project and did all the APNS overhead, but when I run the new app I'm not getting the location permission request dialog at all.

I've gone through all the steps and got to the point where the project is stripped down to the absolute bare minimum:

1. Create new project
2. Put in the location authorization code - requestAlwaysAuthorization() and requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
3. Add in the necessary plist entries - NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription and NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription

Now comes the strange part: when the project is created under a new name XXX, I get the permission request dialog.  But when it is given the name I actually want, which is YYY (for which I've created the App ID, provisioning profile, .pem files, etc.), I don't get the permission dialog at all.

There is absolutely no difference between the two projects since I've created a set of scrap files from which I am cutting and pasting all the code.

Any ideas of what voodoo could be going on behind the scenes that is causing the two projects to be different somehow?

Answer (score 0):

Does your new project share the same bundle ID as the one that had previously triggered the prompt?  You can reset the simulator with iOS Simulator > Reset Content and Settings or on a device in Settings > General > Reset > Reset Locations & Privacy to ensure that you get the prompt again.